# Print stacktrace into file

Tags: java, logging

I have this error stack trace method which sends to log4j error messages:

```
public void writeErrorStackMessage(String message)
    {
        log.error(message);
    }
```

I want also to add printing of stack trace into file.

```
catch (Exception e)
        {
            lm.writeErrorStackMessage(e.printStackTrace());
        }
```

The question is what is the proper way to send the error stack as message?

***Edit:***

```
public void writeErrorStackMessage(String message)
    {
        log.error(message);
    }


catch (Exception e)
        {
            lm.writeErrorStackMessage(Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
        }
```

I modified the code this way.

Comment: You can configure log4j.properties to send the stacktrace into file or write to file using PrrintWriter. What do you want?

Comment: I want to send it as simple error message.

Answer (score 1):

The `e.printStackTrace()` method also takes an PrintWriter or PrintStream argumument so if your `lm` object has an OutputStream you should be able to do

```
e.printStackTrace(new PrintStream (lm.getOutputStream ()));
```

Comment: I modified the code this way. But is there any more elegant solution?

Comment: what is in-elegant about it?

Comment: Is there a way to do this without Arrays?

Comment: In that case just use the Exception `getmessage ()` method